# Download files from sql-server with an specific name using mvc2010

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am creating an application in **c#** with **mvc 2010 Express** and at some point, the user can upload a file and **open/download** it to/from the database.
Here is the table in which I store the files:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tClientsFiles](  
    [IdClient] [int] NOT NULL,  
    [IdFile] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,  
    [Name] [varchar](256) NULL,  
    [Type] [varchar](256) NULL,  
    [Lenght] [money] NULL,  
    [Content] [varbinary](max) NULL,  
    [DateAdd] [datetime] NULL,  
    [UserAdd] [varchar](50) NULL)
```

In tClientsFiles.Name, I store the path and name of the file with: `uploadFile.FileName;`, where `uploadFile` is an `HttpPostedFileBase`. So for insance, if the file is `Test.txt` and it is in the User's Desktop, it stores `C:\Users\user\Desktop\test.txt`

Then, when viewing/downloading the file, I have a link to an `ActionResult` in my `Controller`:

```cs
public ActionResult GetFile(int id)
    {
        var file = dre.tClientsFiles.First(m => m.IdFile == id);

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(file.Content, 0, 0, true, true);
        Response.ContentType = file.Type;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + file.Name);
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Clear();
        Response.OutputStream.Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, ms.GetBuffer().Length);
        Response.OutputStream.Flush();
        Response.End();
        return new FileStreamResult(Response.OutputStream, file.Type);
    }
```

When opening the file, it names it with its "Name" `file.Name`, like this: `c_Users_user_Desktop_Test`.

My question is: is there a way (maybe modifying my `Response.AddHeader`) to **name it with just its "real name"?** (I mean, in our example: `Test`)
**Or** maybe a way to **store the Name in a different way** so that it just stores its "real name" instead of the name and its whole path?

Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + Path.GetFileName(file.Name));
```

Comment: Its just what I needed! Thanks a lot!
(Change GetFilename for GetFileName, cause if not it does not recognise it)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the file name without the extension ie the .txt bit then

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name));
```

Path is in the System.IO namespace.

Comment: I erased my previous comment here, as I realised this is a valid answer as well, but without the extension. Sorry, yesterday I was on a hurry. As I can't give 2 accepted answers, I gave it to the first one that commented here. Thanks a lot for your time!